# Removing dataframe columns with too many missing values

Tags: dataframe, julia

I want to remove columns from a df if they contain more than a given proportion of missing values.

I can do it in a clunky, non-idiomatic way like this:

```
using DataFrames
df = DataFrame(
    "A" => [1, 7, 2],
    "B" => [3, missing, -3],
    "C" => [3, 0, 6],
    "D" => [missing, 4, 2],
    "E" => [4, 3, -4])

nmis = describe(df, :nmissing)
filter!(row -> (row.nmissing / nrow(df) ) > 0.2, nmis)
for v in eachrow(nmis)
    var=v.variable
    select!(df, Not("$var"))
end
println(describe(df))
```

```
3×7 DataFrame
 Row │ variable  mean     min    median   max    nmissing  eltype   
     │ Symbol    Float64  Int64  Float64  Int64  Int64     DataType
─────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
   1 │ A         3.33333      1      2.0      7         0  Int64
   2 │ C         3.0          0      3.0      6         0  Int64
   3 │ E         1.0         -4      3.0      4         0  Int64
```

If I try to be a bit cleverer and use something more idiomatic (on the same df), I get:

```
for col in eachcol(df)
    println(count(ismissing, col))
end
println(describe(df[!, [any(x -> count(ismissing, x) < 1, col) for col in eachcol(df)]]))
```

Next, I would try to divide by `nrow(df)` if I could get this last line to work.

```
0
1
0
1
0
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching iterate(::Missing)

Closest candidates are:
  iterate(::Union{LinRange, StepRangeLen})
   @ Base range.jl:880
  iterate(::Union{LinRange, StepRangeLen}, ::Integer)
   @ Base range.jl:880
  iterate(::T) where T<:Union{Base.KeySet{<:Any, <:Dict}, Base.ValueIterator{<:Dict}}
   @ Base dict.jl:698
  ...

Stacktrace:
  [1] iterate(::Base.Generator{Missing, typeof(ismissing)})
    @ Base .\generator.jl:44
  [2] _simple_count_helper(g::Base.Generator{Missing, typeof(ismissing)}, init::Int64)
    @ Base .\reduce.jl:1356
  [3] _simple_count(pred::Function, itr::Missing, init::Int64)
    @ Base .\reduce.jl:1352
  [4] count(f::Function, itr::Missing; init::Int64)
    @ Base .\reduce.jl:1350
  [5] count(f::Function, itr::Missing)
    @ Base .\reduce.jl:1350
  [6] (::var"#6#8")(x::Missing)
    @ Main c:\Users\TGebbels\OneDrive - The National Lottery Community Fund\Documents\360Giving\ShrinkCSV.jl:26
  [7] _any
    @ .\reduce.jl:1215 [inlined]
  [8] #any#829
    @ .\reducedim.jl:1004 [inlined]
  [9] any
    @ .\reducedim.jl:1004 [inlined]
 [10] (::var"#5#7")(col::Vector{Union{Missing, Int64}})
    @ Main .\none:0
 [11] iterate
    @ .\generator.jl:47 [inlined]
 [12] collect_to!(dest::Vector{Bool}, itr::Base.Generator{DataFrames.DataFrameColumns{DataFrame}, var"#5#7"}, offs::Int64, st::Int64)
    @ Base .\array.jl:840
 [13] collect_to_with_first!(dest::Vector{Bool}, v1::Bool, itr::Base.Generator{DataFrames.DataFrameColumns{DataFrame}, var"#5#7"}, st::Int64)
    @ Base .\array.jl:818
 [14] collect(itr::Base.Generator{DataFrames.DataFrameColumns{DataFrame}, var"#5#7"})
    @ Base .\array.jl:792
 [15] top-level scope
    @ c:\Users\TGebbels\OneDrive ...\Documents\360Giving\ShrinkCSV.jl:26
in expression starting at c:\Users\TGebbels\OneDrive ...\Documents\360Giving\ShrinkCSV.jl:26
```

Separately, I can iterate on `eachcol` and I can count `missing` but somehow not together.

In reality, my df has 330 columns and 350,000 rows. Each column has between no missing values and every value missing.

Is there an idiomatic way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is:

```
select!(df, 
  [i for (i,c) in enumerate(eachcol(df)) 
   if count(ismissing, c) < 0.2*length(c)])
```

idiomatic enough?

The output with the `df` in the question:

```
 Row │ A      C      E     
     │ Int64  Int64  Int64 
─────┼─────────────────────
   1 │     1      3      4
   2 │     7      0      3
   3 │     2      6     -4
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes, this does the trick. For me, the more idiomatic code is, the harder it is to understand. The logic of this is easy but, as a beginner, I don't get how it is composed into a single statement.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe directly using the boolean values as indices

```
df[:,(count.(eachcol(ismissing.(df))) / nrow(df)) .<= 0.2]
```

```
3×3 DataFrame
 Row │ A      C      E
     │ Int64  Int64  Int64
─────┼─────────────────────
   1 │     1      3      4
   2 │     7      0      3
   3 │     2      6     -4
```

Comment: Thank you. This also works for me. But again, as idiomatic code, I don't understand how it works - specifically boolean values as indices. I guess it's back to the docs for me!